# ERROR [Error: notifee.displayNotification(*) 'notification' expected an object value.]

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

```
    const onDisplayNotification = async () => {
    
  await notifee.displayNotification({
    title: 'Notification Title',
    body: 'Main body content of the notification',
    android: {
      channelId,
      // color:'#9c27b0',
      // backgroundColor:'transparent',
      style: {
        type: AndroidStyle.BIGTEXT,
        text: 'Large volume of text shown in the expanded state',
      },
      smallIcon: 'ic_launcher', // optional, defaults to 'ic_launcher'.
      // pressAction is needed if you want the notification to open the app when pressed
      badgeIconType: AndroidBadgeIconType.SMALL,
      badge: true, // disable in badges
      pressAction: {
        id: 'default',
      },
    },
  });
};
```

> above code is an error in notifee.displaynotification in my code.so    kindly help this error